# Inserting JPEG to mysql by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

I have i little problem with inserting .jpg image to database by PHP script. DB connection is working fine for sure, query is working in phpmyadmin, so I think the problem is in the PHP code. There is my db table:

```
CREATE TABLE images(
imageid INT( 11 ) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
noteid INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
image LONGBLOB NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY ( noteid ) REFERENCES notes( noteid ) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

And there is the script for test:

```
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$path = "uploads/1_image_003.jpg";
$noteid = 3;
if(file_exists($path)) {

    $handle = fopen($path, "rb");

    $image = fread($handle, filesize($path));

    fclose($handle);

    $img = base64_encode($image);

    $sql ="INSERT INTO images(noteid, image) VALUES('$noteid', '$img')";

    mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad Query');
    if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
        echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
    }
} else {
    echo "File not found\n";
}
```

That script returning "Bad Query". Do you have any suggestions what is wrong or could you direct me to another way to store .jpg image to mysql?

Comment: why your saving the real image in your db? you can just save the name of the image file into your db

Comment: Why do you want to insert image in database? Instead you should just store file path in db.

Comment: Avoid mysql_* functions... Anyway try replacing 'Bad query' with mysql_error and see what is the error mssg that you receive.

Comment: '$noteid' should not not be in quotes

Comment: @CodingAnt, it doesn't matter. Quotes will work for `INT` too

Comment: @Log1c correct bro , my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents)

```
$img =mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($path));
$sql ="INSERT INTO images(noteid, image) VALUES('$noteid', '$img')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad Query : '.mysql_error());
```

*Note:*

1. You should avoid using `mysql_*` functions, you should use [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.
2. Don't store files to database (unless its extremely required). You could just store file path to database. for [more..](http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1379/best-practice-store-images-in-db-or-on-file-system.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad Query');
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```

with

```
if ( !mysql_query($sql) ) { // Error handling
    die( 'Bad Query' . mysql_error() );
}
```

You should consider using [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead of `mysql_query()` since it is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to debug this a little bit further to determine the problem.

Add the following before your code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Also, as suggested below try replacing:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad Query');
```

With

```
mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad Query'. mysql_error());
```